# v-for produces error on IE11

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internet-explorer-11

I have a simple vue instance which produces table from data array. Document renders fine on Firefox and Chrome but in IE11 i'm getting an error:

> [Vue warn]: Error when rendering root instance.

I thought Vue is compatible with 'modern browsers' but when started to find compatibility information inside vue documentation I found nothing.

Anyway, do you have any ideas on how to solve this issue?

```js
        // initializing
        var notesView = new Vue({
            el: '#demo',
            data: {
                notes: []
            },
            methods: {
            }
        });

notesView.notes = JSON.parse('[{"noteTime":"2018-07-30T22:00:00.000Z","locationName":"Q3000010","noteText":"NoteText0"},{"noteTime":"2018-07-31T22:00:00.000Z","locationName":"Q3000020","noteText":"NoteText1"}]');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-if="notes.length > 0">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tbody>
        <template v-for="(note,index) in notes">
          <tr class="condensed" :class="index % 2 === 0 ? 'odd' : ''">
            <td width="150px">
              {{ note.noteTime }}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ note.locationName }}
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr :class="index % 2 === 0 ? 'odd' : ''">
            <td colspan="2">
              {{ note.noteText }}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div v-else="">
    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
      There are no notes here yet...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: IE11 is supported (only from IE8 down things start to get aweful/unsolvable), and I have used it with my components pulled through babel. Does the console of IE11 give any more information about the error?

Comment: Not much: „index” is undefined (or something similar i console is in polish language)

Comment: [IE11 does not support `template` tags](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template). You'll need to move your template into a string template, or use a render function.

Comment: Ok, i'll check the syntax. I would prefer not to define separate component for that.

Comment: @Bert can it be done without defining new component?

Comment: Yes, see this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47873321/38065

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. Anyway IE sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me. I'm using x-template script to bypass IE11 limitations - that compromises code readability and a need of special care for IE...

```js
// initializing grid control
        var notesView = new Vue({
            el: '#notes',
            template: '#v-notes-view',
            data: {
                notes: []
            },
            methods: {
            }
        });

notesView.notes = JSON.parse('[{"noteTime":"2018-07-30T22:00:00.000Z","locationName":"Q3000010","noteText":"NoteText0"},{"noteTime":"2018-07-31T22:00:00.000Z","locationName":"Q3000020","noteText":"NoteText1"}]');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="notes">
</div>
<script type="text/x-template" id="v-notes-view">
<div v-if="notes.length > 0">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <template v-for="(note,index) in notes">
        <tr class="condensed" :class="index % 2 === 0 ? 'odd' : ''">
          <td width="150px">
            {{ note.noteTime }}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{ note.locationName }}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr :class="index % 2 === 0 ? 'odd' : ''">
          <td colspan="2">
            {{ note.noteText }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div v-else="">
  <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
    There are no notes here yet...
  </div>
</div>
</script>
```